# Can't Run Netbeans after changing Java to 1.6 on mac

Tags: java, macos, unix, netbeans, environment-variables

i know i've posting a lot about mac lately and setting up my environment to develop on java 1.6.
after trying to set my etc/launch.conf like so

> setenv JAVA_VERSION 1.6
>   setenv JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
>   setenv CATALINA_BASE /Library/apache-tomcat6020
>   setenv CATALINA_HOME /Library/apache-tomcat6020
>   setenv CATALINA_TMPDIR /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/temp

and with sodu i can't run my java with 1.6 it was still 1.5 so i found online some workarounds

```
rm Current*  
ln -s 1.6.0/ Current
ln -s 1.6.0/ CurrentJDK
```

i works untill i restart the machine and then i cannot run eclipse no netbeans any more.Netbeans start and stop few seconds after and eclipse spit out error code =-1.
I just want to come back to 1.5 and see.Java parameter behave the same way as NetBeans. i did the same link stuf for 1.5 by removing the current and create the new link, and updating /etc/launchd.conf to 1.5 no success after restarting the machine. java -version give 1.6.0_15 both on normal user and sudo.
What do you think i should do? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at **Applications/Utilities/Java**?
You can switch between different versions of Java there, permanently.

Comment: yeah bruv it's simply not starting.i mean it start few seconds and vanish later

Answer (score 0):

Solved part of it by doing

```
rm ~/Library/Caches/Java/deployment.properties
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0
sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6
```

Netbeans started working again.But there is one problem though.When i type java i got

> -bash: java: command not found

but javac and applerviewer can be run.I guess for that one some one can help me thought it.thanks for reading.
Ps: for some in the same situation as me i've read you might have to delete Java SE 6 in /Applications/Utilities/Java if there is one

Answer (score 0):

You should never, ever delete anything in `/System` (except the contents of `/System/Library/Caches` if needed for troubleshooting).  Reinstall Java 6 (with Apple's latest Java update) before you do anything else, then if you want to change the VM NetBeans uses, either use Java Preferences or add to `~/.netbeans/«version»/etc/netbeans.conf`:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home"
```

Comment: thanks for the advice i've come to realise that.So there are things i believe i don't understand. `when you say Reinstall Java 6 (with Apple's latest)` you mean the next time there is an update. i messed up the 1.6.0_15 so you mean when the 1.6.0_17 will be available? i'm asking because the software updater still thinks that i have the 1.6.0_15 and then not showing me the option to Reinstall it.

Comment: You can download 1.6.0_15 manually to reinstall it. (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL924).